# Javascript search box

Tags: javascript, html, api

I need to have a search box and based on the search item, I need to form an URL and use it for a search API. I am confused as to how to use the text input in the search box in a HTML. Once I get this variable, I could use this to form my URL. Could you help me on extracting a search string from the entered value in the search box?

Comment: Create a textarea, onclick (or onblur) get its value, URI encode it and add it to the base URL as a query string.  Does that look like what you're after?  What have you tried already?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<textarea id = "query">My search string</textarea>
<button id = "search">Click Me</button>
```

JS

```
$('#search').click(function() {
   var q = $('#query').val();
   var query = encodeURIComponent(q);
   alert('myUrl.com/q=' + query + '');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1xeqjw8e/1/) here.